# Textbook RSA signature forgery when e=65537

Tags: rsa, signature, forgery

Searching about RSA signature forgery I came across [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24824/what-use-is-the-signature-without-the-message-under-rsa).
In the answer, it is stated that

> for small to moderate $e$ (including $e=3$ and $e=2^{16}+1$, often used in practice), it would be possible to forge a large class of messages, including C strings showing as anything desired. For any $m_0$, it is easy to exhibit $m_1$ such that $m=m_0||m_1$ is the (non-modular) e-th power of a known integer $\sigma$ (compute $\sigma=⌈\sqrt[e]{m_0 2^{2e|N|}}⌉$ and $m_1 = \sigma^e − m_0 2^{2e|n|}$ of size $2e|N|$ bit); this $\sigma$ verifies as the signature for $m$; and $m$ prints the same as $m_0$ if $m_0$ is a zero-terminated C-string.

And actually I am having a hard time seeing how this can work with $e = 2^{16}+1$.
I would say that $\sigma$ will most probably be greater than the modulus $N$ in this case and the reduction will make everything fall apart.

Should there be a condition on

> $m_1 = \sigma^e − m_0 2^{2e|n|}$ of size $2e|N|$ bit

and thus the forgery shall work for $e = 2^{16}+1$ but only with a very large modulus and not standard 1024-/2048-/4096-bit ones?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoted answer is about a question with

> To verify, the receiver checks that $\sigma^e \equiv m \pmod N$. (…)
> Given $m \pmod N$ but an unknown $m$ (…)

Thus in the context it does not necessarily hold $0\le m<N$ as in the textbook RSA signature scheme of [the original article](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf). Rather, the question considers an hypothetical signature system where $m$ can be larger than $N$, and the message is signed as an appendix $\sigma\gets m^d\bmod N$, sent independently of the message.

The line of attack in [the old answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/24835/10) is ridiculously complex for this setup. Here is a simpler attack that works for any $e$, and if the receiver checks $0\le\sigma<N$ in addition to the question's $\sigma^e \equiv m \pmod N$.

The attacker

- chooses $\sigma$ freely in $[0,N)$, including $0$, and $1$ and $N-1$ which would simplify computation.
- decides $m_0$, e.g. ending with an 0x00 byte acting as a $C$ string terminator
- if $N$ is $n$-bit, decides that $m_1$ [to me appended to $m_0$ forming $m=m_0\mathbin\|m_1$ ] will be a bitstring of $b=8\lceil n/8\rceil$ bit
- computes $m\gets m_0\,2^b+((\sigma^e-m_0\,2^b)\bmod N)$.

I'll make an example with $N=$[RSA-2048](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-2048), $e=2^{16}+1$, $\sigma=3^{1291}$, message $m$ printing as the 15-byte `A test message.` in ASCII. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVTLbttIELzzKyYIAoqW5fRjXm1Yh1xy9GlzCoLAWo1kARFlkEzinP2B/iRtjSzEBpYHEl3T3VVdPeDDn@n@0Gt@GI7HW7d0EtiCUfYpxJCyqTdPkjireCKf1XJI7MUkC0sU8qSCBDysKWskrxGwUKIULIQQJXriHCTkTCl7T9E4i1H0LN4CB0KrbILOwdgbp8jZB5IMGdlYiJKgzkxiTgrmGoMwJg0GMRDnkyQS1FnUFAhdIFk8mDgGQiqrJhAYWUhEZEmVPKp9rixoT5wQiTFBmPiQq0pOcIM5Jx9ZGFI5SQw@qmB84Ygkyyn4OpAX8aqgl@pfqLJqKhzSAKkGFtUMWT4l730yWKQGg0VjwKCitUdmtsxRM2xhitDH0MkxkqakFAl@Eke2mKKEOhacYXhOmlWNamBBonqvwkbMHnsMIAye4T62KGRwBr5wSJBU7clYVvJW55WQEo6TRewYOqIGzKSSzaoFuAFgg0LcDcs5YP9orVixaJCEExiGixAxVPRaa6CXFPt48QxTC8GRptTbdnHBcc7NnpZu109Xm@Gw/776M5Vx9vJuPzl8Jrcv43i3LVftpWu//PN5kdvu0tWUw7Auw7Jd7bY4GnfbvqyXn@9@jKW7ucnN8xNIFCTYa9Osy8bdl0eZ9d114/C8d/8e@l9lmCq5mw711P3eTfeu/Cq963/uV2Vwh41b77a7aXR3mwnxj3K33vVbR4/uMLgFPZ56jWBCOXqfwt0Gef1s7D7IuyW90J3x8St9e7dsF@31qailR2rn41e5/nbKKhD/v/zlm/zFuUDPBUOZfg69G5umx/Ht1Wo3fQf3drqfdc0K0Kyfp@7jx3yRm30N93Rzs@rms9nD4ffs@emyXN52izPafbjtmocBfsza@j9o5yfHbru/aHlFyyt6cvoMPz@94nWzZ3hPb@DX7P1f9I2c5XIPIcfj8T8).

---

That said, the [old answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/24835/10) was bogus, I [fixed it](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24835/555); and the present question is right to state that with $0\le m<N$ (common in textbook RSA), an attack is possible for very small $e$ like $e=3$ but fails for $e=65537$ and usual size of $N$.

Comment: Ok, this is indeed really more simple and works perfectly! In the meantime, I had a look at [Extending Bleichenbacher's Forgery Attack](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/imt/3/4/3_4_780/_article) which, although it does not really talk about that, gives some more details about the relation between the size of $N$ and the use of $\sqrt[e]{}$ depending on $e$
Thanks for the answer!