# Why is RSA-2048 max input 245 bytes?

Tags: rsa, public-key, key-size

I can see that the message (after padding) should not be 256 bytes because it might be bigger than the modulus of RSA. So I think that the message should be 255 bytes, but I saw posts that says the maximum input is 245 bytes. Why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to RSA with PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, as defined in [section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.2) of RFC 3447 (PKCS#1 v2.1):

> ```
> 2. EME-PKCS1-v1_5 encoding:
>
>       a. Generate an octet string PS of length k - mLen - 3 consisting
>          of pseudo-randomly generated nonzero octets.  The length of PS
>          will be at least eight octets.
>
>       b. Concatenate PS, the message M, and other padding to form an
>          encoded message EM of length k octets as
>
>             EM = 0x00 || 0x02 || PS || 0x00 || M.
> ```

As you can see there are three overhead bytes and a minimum of 8 bytes of random padding.

Without the padding RSA encryption would be deterministic and *[not secure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20085/which-attacks-are-possible-against-raw-textbook-rsa)*.

---

Originally the RSA encryption scheme has mostly been used with PKCS#1 v1.5 defined padding. No other schemes were all that popular at the time. So it is most likely that PKCS#1 v1.5 is implicitly used when no padding scheme is indicated.

Officially the name should be RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5-ENCRYPT of course, but nobody uses the function names directly.

---

Note that there are other modes of padding such as OAEP (defined in the same RFC), which is more secure. For new protocols PKCS#1 padding should not be used anymore. If you're stuck with an old protocol that requires PKCS#1 unpadding, you should make sure that padding / decryption oracles do not apply.

Comment: I just want to emphasize that **PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption padding is weak and should not be used**. Unless both protocol and implementation carefully step around its weaknesses you'll likely end up with a decryption oracle.