# How to sign with RSA safely?

Tags: rsa, signature

what should I do to make my RSA signatures secure? If "plaintext RSA" is not secure, is there some sort of "RSA on steroids" I am not aware of? Could anybody tell me what is it?

I read a Wikipedia article "Digital signature". In the ["History"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature#History) chapter we can see:

> ...Soon afterwards, Ronald Rivest, Adi Shamir, and Len Adleman
>   invented the RSA algorithm, which could be used to produce primitive
>   digital signatures (although only as a proof-of-concept – "plain"
>   RSA signatures are not secure

I searched for "rsa signature is not secure" but didn't find anything legible. Does anybody know why are RSA signatures are not secure and how can I make it secure by not doing "plain" signatures? Are there any tricks? The thing is that recently I implemented RSA in my code for my project and was so excited to see that I can sign and verify things with RSA...

Comment: Search for "textbook RSA", which is a more common name what that quote calls "plain RSA".

Comment: You should either use Full-Domain-Hash or PSS padding for RSA signatures.

Comment: Ilmari, that page describes insecurities of RSA... But what can be done to prevent it? What is "not a plaintext RSA"? Is there some kind of "RSA on Steroids" I am not aware of?

Comment: The section 'Some digital signature algorithms' further down that page links to RSA-PSS among others. Even RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (signature) is still secure in practice (if correctly implemented) although not provably and it is no longer preferred. In contrast RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 (_encryption_) is broken in many practical cases by an attack due to Bleichenbacher (who is easy to google). Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20085/which-attacks-are-possible-against-raw-textbook-rsa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main modern standard RSA-based signature scheme is RSASSA-PSS in [PKCS#1 v2](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf), also standardized as IETF [RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017) (v2.2, obsoletes [v2.1 in RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447)).  This is a variant of [PSS proposed and analyzed by Bellare and Rogaway in 1996](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/exact.pdf).

**Beware: RSASSA-PSS as standardized by RSA, Inc., in the early 2000s, around the same time as Dual_EC_DRBG,<sup>*</sup> is vulnerable to collisions in the underlying hash function** by virtue of using $H(r \mathbin\Vert H(m))$, instead of $H(r \mathbin\Vert m)$, which would have required of $H$ the much more modest security property [(enhanced) target collision resistance](https://iacr.org/archive/crypto2006/41170039/41170039.pdf).  This vulnerability to collisions led to a technique for [practical HTTPS certificate forgery by academics](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/), and to a [*different* technique for certificate forgery](http://max-fillinger.net/papers/F13-msc-thesis-flame.pdf) used in an international incident of industrial sabotage by the United States and Israel against Iran.

**If you need to get code running right now *and for some reason you need to use RSA***, that's the practical answer.  If you need to get code running right now but you don't actually need to use RSA, use [Ed25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA) instead—except for verification speed, it is an all-around faster, safer, and compacter signature scheme.

**If you are studying existing code or an existing protocol that was not designed by a competent cryptographer,** and you are wondering whether it uses a state-of-the-art signature scheme, you should expect it to use either RSASSA-PSS or PKCS#1 v1.5 signature.  If it doesn't, your eyebrows should be raised and whoever designed it has some justifyin' to do.

**If you are intellectually absorbed by the wonders of the world of cryptography,** or if like me you're a bone-eating vulture who likes blathering at strangers on the internet about things you've learned, then you should also know about full-domain hash, which was discarded [essentially for political reasons among cryptographers](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/140) but is easy to implement and instantiate with modern XOFs like SHAKE256, and [Rabin–Williams signatures](https://cr.yp.to/sigs.html), which are [more efficient](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#rwsota) with a [tighter security reduction](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#rwtight).  But make sure you know what you're trying to achieve before you go down that rabbit hole!

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> I have no evidence to support a connection here, but coincidences like these are remarkably good at playing evidence in games of charades at parties.</sub>

Comment: Do you have a link to the spec of that different RSASSA-PSS standardized in the early 2000s?

Comment: @fgrieu No, I just mean the standard RSASSA-PSS we all know and love, or love to hate, is designed this way.  In a little more detail: the message $M$ figures in via $H(0^{64} \mathbin\Vert H(M) \mathbin\Vert \mathit{salt})$.  (See p. 37 of PKCS#1 v2.2, or p. 43 of RFC 8017.)  If it had instead been $H(0^{64} \mathbin\Vert \mathit{salt} \mathbin\Vert M)$, then there would be no need for collision resistanc (unless the entropy source used to generate $\mathit{salt}$ is predictable).

Comment: Understood. Indeed, entering an unpredictable value early in the data of a hash used for signature lessens the pressure on the hash.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage, I just need signing system in my project, the only condition is that it must be secure, so I go for Ed25519. Thank you for help!

Answer (score -1):

When talking about "plain" RSA, it is referencing standard RSA without any sort of random padding. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding talks about this OAEP type of RSA. Problems with the plain format include that it is malleable and deterministic. OAEP solves these problems.

Comment: OAEP is padding for encryption, hence the name '... Encryption Padding'. The equivalent for signature is Probablistic Signature Scheme PSS as explained by Squeamish.