# RSA PADDING WITH e=3

Tags: encryption, rsa, cryptanalysis, padding, decryption

I have a ciphertext which has been padded with spaces from left the message is 31 bytes long and e = 3 how can I recover the message with python code .

Comment: Do you have the private key or are you requesting cryptanalysis of it?

Comment: Welcome to crypto-SE! Precise description matters in cryptanalysis. In RSA, padding is usually applied not to the _ciphertext_, but to the _plaintext_ (the message). Padding turns the message into an integer $m$, then encrypted by $c\gets m^e\bmod N$. How characters are encoded into $m$ is important. Assuming plaintext padding with space encoded to digit zero, and (per standard assumption) known public modulus, this question is among the [common attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20085/555), and was thus closed. If that's inadequate, edit the question with details, and ask reopening.